# Multiple Service definition in cloud formation template (YAML)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS Cluster by the name cluster-01 and under that cluster I have one service running which basically have few tasks associated to integrate microservices.

I want to add another service but want to use the same yaml template i.e single file for multiple service definition with assocated task definition defined with them.

I am pretty new to YAML and I created a single cluster with one service using AWS template available in their website.

If someone can help out to understand if it's possible to incorporate another service for same cluster by using single yaml template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple AWS::ECS::Service resources defined in one template file:

```
ecsService1:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    (...)

ecsService2:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    (...)
```